# When does the IsBusy property change on a BackgroundWorker?

Tags: .net, backgroundworker

The `BackgroundWorker` component has an `IsBusy` flag. While it's executing `RunWorkerASync`, this flag is set to True. Does it change to False when `RunWorkerASync` finishes, or when `RunWorkerCompleted` finishes?

Answer (score -1):

The `IsBusy` flag will be set to false as soon as `RunWorkerASync` ends, before `RunWorkerCompleted` executes. Say you wanted to retrieve the results of the `BackgroundWorker`'s operation from another function like so:

```
Dim MyResult = "Not Set"

Sub Foo()

    DoSomeStuff()

    RunWorkerASync()

    'Wait for worker
    While Worker.IsBusy
        Wait()
    End While

    'Use result
    'This won't work because MyResult hasn't been
    'set yet by the RunWorkerCompleted handler
    'Will Print "Not Set", unless, by a timing quirk,
    'RunWorkerCompleted has enough time to execute
    'Before using its result.
    Print MyResult
End Sub

Sub RunWorkerASync()
    e.Result = "Result has been set"
End Sub

Sub RunWorkerCompleted()
    MyResult = e.Result 'Worker's output
End Sub
```

Comment: "before RunWorkerCompleted executes" - this is not true, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13140439/453803